# Powershell foreach loop for csv files and save to different folder

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, foreach

I am trying to read multiple csv in a folder and trying to replace few unwanted characters and saving it to another csv with same name in a different folder.

I tried using `foreach` loop and `ForEach-Object` loop to dynamically generate destination file name

```
#CSV's in folder (ABC.csv, DEF.csv)

param ( [String] $Filename))

$SourceFolderPath = Get-Childitem "C:\data\"
$DestinationFolderPath =  "C:\data\cleaned\"

$Source = $SourceFolderPath + $FileName
$Destination = $DestinationFolderPath + $Filename

ForEach ($f in $SourceFolderPath) {$F}
{

Import-Csv $f | ForEach-Object -Begin { $writeHeader = $True } {
  if ($writeHeader) { $writeHeader = $False; $_.psobject.properties.Name -join ',' }
  $_.psobject.properties.Value -replace ',', '' -replace '"', '' -join ','

} | set-Content $Destination

}
```

The code is running if I manually pass `$FileName = "ABC.csv"`. But I need it to dynamically do this for all the files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to clean all column data from contained commas and
also remove all double quotes from the resulting csv files?

I suggest to define defaults for the param strings,
so you ***can*** supply other values if desired, but you don't have to.

The script temporarily changes the delimiter to a vertical bar `|` ,
so this shouldn't occur in the file content.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\27\SO_57678154.ps1

param ( [String] $Filename  = '*.csv',
        [String] $SourceDir = 'C:\Data\',
        [String] $TargetDir = 'C:\Data\cleaned\'
)

ForEach ($csvFile in Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Filter $Filename){
    (Import-Csv $csvFile | 
     ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|') -replace '[,"]' -replace '\|',',' |
         Set-Content (Join-Path $TargetDir $csvFile.Name)                  
}
```