# CSV file not processing in concatenation if not saved manually

Tags: python, azure, csv, concatenation

I am trying to run a python code that grabs data from daily csv files and processes to create a dataframe that meets the requirement.

This is code that runs **fine** (if I open csv file, **saved** and run):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO   

def read_block(names, igidx=True):
    with open("Test_11_17_2023.csv") as f: 
        pat = r"(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})"
        return pd.concat([
            pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
                .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                    pat, f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S) if m.group(1) in names 
        ], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)

df = read_block(names=["Admissions", "Readmissions"],  
     igidx=False).droplevel(1).reset_index(names="block")
print(df)
```

If I just run the code where it just read data, there is no issue (even if the file is not opened and saved manually):

```
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.read_csv("Test_11_17_2023.csv")
print(df)
```

First, I thought it is just the security setting of csv file, but even I checked the "Unblock", my python code still would not able to run to process within "concat"/Regex.

[image]

But, whenever I get a new csv file (meaning "not saved manually again"), it creates this error (concat).

[image]

My question is, is there anything making it difficult to concatenate data if csv file is not saved?  I am not sure it is just general concat issue or Regex issue.

How do I modify the existing code to run without concat error issue?

This is how it looks like when I originally get the csv file.
I generated file in csv format from txt file.

[image]

Bottom is the result from comparing both files (original (doesn't work) and saved one (works)) using an app called [Meld](https://meld.app/):

[image]

This is image from Cygwin (updated 11/25):
[image]

Comment: Split up the `pd.concat` in multiple pieces - do at most one thing at a time, then debug the values of each part, and update your post with each of the values. Seems like one of your parts is empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "not saved manually"?

Comment: There is _nothing_ in this regex `(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})` that will parse a csv string, nothing .

Comment: @drum If I just use a csv file downloaded from original source, and try to process, it would not run. But when I open that file and save it, it works.

Comment: what do you download? where do you download? Maybe you download it in wrong way and you get wrong file (ie. with wrong encoding) but when you open and save it again then it corrects mistake (ie. it corrects encoding) and file works. You could use `print()` to see if both versions are the same. Or you could use tools like [Meld](https://meld.app/) to compare files.

Comment: @furas I think you got the good point. I create file into csv format using Azure Logic App (from HTTP (get method)), and I think it it created as txt file. I added an image on the top.

Comment: `csv` is always text file. But sometimes it may have `BOM` (`Byte Order Mark`)  at the beginning and some tools may have problem to work with this.

Comment: @furas I don't think the the file has BOM objects. The image illustration looks kinda weird because I had to erase some confidential info with eraser on Paint. So far (after testing so many times), this code only works  when csv file is opened and saved (as if it is confirmed as trusted source?).

Comment: as I sad before - maybe use `Meld` to compare (byte-by-byte) two files - original and saved again.

Comment: @furas I just did the comparison using Meld. 
I posted the image of result. It appears that original file was saved in UNIX (LF) and the one that works is saved in DOS/Windows (CR-LF). How should I modify the code? I tried with both   with open("file_orig.csv", "w") or with open("file_orig.csv", "rU") based on what I searched online, and both cause errors.

Comment: how about `content = content.replace('\n', '\r\n')` without saving and reading. Or maybe you should use `\r\n` in regex.

Comment: @furas When I tried with Meld again, I realized that with the original csv file, it added " around some characters, and also it deleted comma. I think if there is a way to convert csv file itself from Unix format to Windows format, it would work. How do I go about doing in Python?

Comment: You can use the `dos2unix` command to fix a file's newlines.

Comment: @Barmar I was able to download Cygwin64 (because dos2unix was not easy to install). What is command to convert from Unix file to Windows file? I have attached an image on the top.

Comment: on Linux it is `unix2dos input.csv output.csv`. I don't use Windows but I think it will need the same `unix2dos` or  `/full/path/to/unix2dos`

Comment: @furas I ended up using a PowerShell script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678154/powershell-foreach-loop-for-csv-files-and-save-to-different-folder), and it seems to be working fine now.