# How to convert Unix (LF format) to Windows (CR-LF) using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert bottom text (Unix (LF format)) - let's say "Unix.csv":

```
Admissions
"Not Started: 1","Sent: 0","Completed: 0"
,,,,
Division,Community,"Resident Name",Date,"Document Status","Last Update"
,"Test","Name",2023-11-22,"Not Started",
,,,,
,,,,
Readmissions
"Not Started: 1","Sent: 0","Completed: 0"
,,,,
Division,Community,"Resident Name",Date,"Document Status","Last Update"
,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 7:29 AM","Not Started",
,,,,
,,,,
Discharges
,,,,
Division,Community,"Resident Name",Date
,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 1:23 AM"
,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 7:49 AM"
,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 1:12 AM"
```

To this (Windows(CR-LF format)) - let's say "Windows.csv" using **Python 3** script?:

```
Admissions,,,,,
Not Started: 1,Sent: 0,Completed: 0,,,
,,,,,
Division,Resident Name,Date,Document Status,Last Update
,Test,Name,11/22/2023,Not Started,
,,,,,
,,,,,
Readmissions,,,,,
Not Started: 1,Sent: 0,Completed: 0,,,
,,,,,
Division,Community,Resident Name,Date,Document Status,Last Update
,Test,Name,11/22/2023 7:29,Not Started,
,,,,,
,,,,,
Discharges,,,,,
,,,,,
Division,Community,Resident Name,Date,,
,Test,Name,11/22/2023 1:23,,
,Test,Name,11/22/2023 7:49,,
,Test,Name,11/22/2023 1:12,,
```

After I tried this code (update):

```
#!/bin/python3
with open('Unix.csv', 'r') as file:
    toWrite = file.read().replace('\n', '\r\n')
with open('Convert.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(toWrite)
```

This is result:

```
Admissions

"Not Started: 1","Sent: 0","Completed: 0"

,,,,

Division,Community,"Resident Name",Date,"Document Status","Last 
Update"

,"Test","name",2023-11-22,"Not 
Started",

,,,,

,,,,

Readmissions

"Not Started: 1","Sent: 0","Completed: 0"

,,,,

Division,Community,"Resident Name",Date,"Document Status","Last 
Update"

,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 7:29 AM","Not Started",

,,,,

,,,,

Discharges

,,,,

Division,Community,"Resident Name",Date

,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 1:23 AM"

,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 
7:49 AM"

,"Test","Name","2023-11-22 1:12 AM"
```

This is another code that I tried:

I am not sure if this is what @furas meant. I tried, but it still would not work.

```
#!/bin/python3
with open('Test.csv', newline="\r\n") as file: 
    toWrite = file.read()
with open('convert.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(toWrite)
```

Comment: @Emily I already tried but it would not work..

Comment: Then ask (or edit this into) a question about _why that existing answer you tried didn't work_ -- that's much more clear and specific than just asking a duplicative question with no clarification about what you attempted and how you tested to determine that that prior attempt was unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't see your script. We can't read in your mind - so we can't help you.

Comment: @furas I just tried code from Blay but still it would not convert as expected.

Comment: frankly, on LInux I would use programs `unix2dos` `dos2unix` instead of using `Python`. Eventually you could try to read and write in `byte-mode`  (`'rb'` `'wb'`) because you write in `text-mode` and it may automatically convert `'\r\n'` back to `'\n'`

Comment: you may also try to write with `open(...., newline="\r\n")` and maybe it will put `\r\n` instead of `\n` in file (without using `replace()`)

Comment: @furas I need to understand your first comment.  I actually tried unix2dos but I am still stuck what the command line I should write. Please see my last comment on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519494/csv-file-not-processing-in-concatenation-if-not-saved-manually). I am trying to know how I should write when you mentioned "maybe it will put \r\n instead of \n in file (without using replace())". I added my latest code on the top.

Comment: in bash/console `unix2dos Test.csv convert.csv`. You have to use `newline` when you write, not when you read. `open('convert.csv', 'w', newline="\r\n")` and it will automatically replace `\n` with `\r\n` in `convert.csv`

Comment: because this question is closed (because it duplicates other question) so I put my answer in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77550202/1832058

Comment: I ended up using a Powershell script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678154/powershell-foreach-loop-for-csv-files-and-save-to-different-folder) and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but for converting a simple text file it would look like that:

```
#!/bin/python3
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    toWrite = file.read().replace('\n', '\r\n')
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(toWrite)
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before". What we're trying to avoid by that rule is having the same answer given attached to more than one question, or having answers spread out across multiple questions; ideally, you would put this answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13954965/14122 if none of the answers there already cover the same ground.